# How to fetch POST values of a dynamically generated form in php

Tags: php

this is my dynamically generated form that allows the user to input scores of students.my challenge is how to capture the specific subjectCode  and its score because am using the subjectcode to store in the database .

```
<?php
$attributes=array('class'=>'','id'=>'');
echo form_open('scoreInsertion/insertScores',$attributes);
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";?>
<label for="admNo>">Admission Number<span class="required">*</span></label>
<?php echo form_error('admNo');
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";?>
<input type="text" name="admNo" id="admNo"  value="<?php echo set_value('admNo')?>"   />
<?php echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";    
?>
<label for="studentName>">Student Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
<?php echo form_error('studentName');
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";?>
<input type="text" name="studentName" id="studentName"  value="<?php echo $studentName?>"   />
<?php echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr></tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
?>
<label for="examCategory">Exam Category<span class="required">*</span></label>
<!--<tr><td><?php echo form_error('examCategory')?></td></tr>-->
<td>
<select name="examCategory">
<option value="">--Select Category--</option>
<?php
print_r($exams);
if(isset($exams) && is_array($exams)){
    foreach($exams as $exam){
        $examId=$exam->id;
        $examName=$exam->category;
        echo "<option value='$examId'>$examName</option>";
    }
}
?>
</select></td><?php
echo "<tr></tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
?>
<label for="term">Academic Term<span class="required">*</span></label>
<!--<tr><td><?php echo form_error('examCategory')?></td></tr>-->
<td>
<select name="term">
<option value="">--Academic Term--</option>
<?php
if(isset($terms) && is_array($terms)){
    foreach($terms as $term){
        $termId=$term->termId;
        $termName=$term->name;
        echo "<option value='$termId'>$termName</option>";
    }
}
?>
</select></td>

<?php
echo "<tr>";
//loop through the subjects array and display them on the view 
if(isset($subjects) && is_array($subjects)){
    foreach($subjects as $subject){
        $subjectName=$subject->subName;
        $subjectCode=$subject->subCode;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<tr></tr>";
        echo "<td>";?>
        <label for="<?php echo $subjectName?>"><?php echo $subjectName;?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo form_error($subjectName);
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";?>
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $subjectCode?>" id="<?php echo $subjectName?>"  value="<?php echo set_value($subjectCode)?>"   />
        <?php echo "</tr>";
        }   
}
?>
<?php echo "<tr>";echo "<td>";
echo form_submit('submit','Submit'); 
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
?>
</p>
<?php
echo "</table>";
echo form_close();
?>
```

PHP script to process the above POST details is below:

```
function insertScores(){
        $admNo=$this->input->post('admNo');
        $term=$this->input->post('term');
        //get the post variables from the Form
        $posted = $this->input->post();
        $x = array_keys($posted);
        foreach($x as $y) {
            echo $y ." = ". $_POST[$y]."<br/>";
            echo "<br>";
            //write the sql 
            $form_data=array(
            'admNo' =>$admNo,
            'subCode'=>$y,
            'termId'=>$term,
            'score'=>$_POST[$y]                     
            );
            print_r($form_data);
            $this->SaveForm($form_data);
        }
}
```

Comment: Is all of this in the same file? because there are no opening and closing tags (`<?php ... ?>`) around the function. And the function is also lacking a closing `}`.

Comment: You should use a [`heredoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). It will help you with formatting output.

Answer (score 0):

If that really has to be, you could set a specific prefix for the `name` attribute and then look for a key starting with that prefix among your `$_POST` keys. Something like that:

```
<input type="text"
       name="subject_<?php echo $subjectCode?>"
       id="<?php echo $subjectName?>"
       value="<?php echo set_value($subjectCode)?>"   />
```

Then search for it in the `$_POST` array.

```
$subjectCode = null;
foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $index) {
    if (strpos($index, 'subject_') === 0) { // you found the needed element            
        // get its value and save it in a variable
        $subjectCode = $_POST[$index];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: the form and the script are different.

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my problem, I fetch the `subCode` using `admNo` in the db then compare with the `POST` names.

```
$subjects=$this->subjectModel->get_subjects();
foreach($subjects as $subject){
    $subCode= $subject->subCode;
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        //print_r($key);
        //print_r($value);
        $form_data=array();
        if($key == $subCode){
            //echo $subCode. "=". $value;
            //write the sql for insertion into the database
            $form_data = array(
            'admNo'=>$admNo,
            'subCode'=>$subCode,
            'termId'=>$term,
            'formId'=>$formstudy,
            'score'=>$value,
            'year'=>$year    


            );
            $this->SaveForm($form_data);    

        }
    }
}
```